# how to package angular component as package which is created without CLI

Tags: angular5

I have created an angular 5 project without using angular CLI, I am running the application using webpack now I want to publish my components as packages to npm so that it can be used any other projects.

please guide me proper documentation to package and publish my angular components.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr), which will transpile your libraries to Angular Package Format.

First of all, you need to have a `package.json` file. Then, add to it the custom `ngPackage` property, and eventually run `ng-packagr -p package.json`.
Paths in the `ngPackage` section are resolved relative to the location of the `package.json` file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/package.schema.json",
  "name": "@my/foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, `public_api.ts` is the entry file to the library's sources and must be placed next to `package.json` (a sibling in the same folder).

Referencing the `$schema` enables JSON editing support (auto-completion for configuration) in IDEs like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

You can easily run *ng-packagr* through a npm/yarn script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng-packagr -p package.json"
  }
}
```

And now, you can execute the build with the following command:

```
$ yarn build
```

The build output is written to the `dist` folder, containing all those *binaries* to meet the Angular Package Format specification. You'll now be able to go ahead and `npm publish dist` your Angular library to the npm registry.

Comment: hey it is expecting angular cli to be present getting folllwing error 
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

Comment: In order to properly work with Angular you need to have the minimun Angular dependecies installed into your project. These are `@angular/common`, `@angular/core`, `@angular/compiler`, `@angular/compiler-cli`, `@angular/platform-browser` and `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`.

Comment: tried installing @angular/compiler-cli and still not packaging can you give me some code which is working without cli and can be packagable using ng-packagr